# Call a function from another class

Tags: java, function, processing

I'm writing a little program for a school project. The theme is "objective Coding" so there's the "main Tab" where the draw method and setup method is. In other tabs, I wrote other classes and functions.

So in the my "main Tab" there's the function `void draw` and it looks like this:

```java
void draw() {               
  background();            
  h1.displayH();
  steuerungH();
  t1.displayT();
}
```

The three methods `background();`, `h1.displayH();` and `t1.displayT();` worked without a problem. I tried writing the code like:

```java
...
...
h1.streuerungH();
...
```

`h1` is an object, a rectangle I try to move with the function `void steuerungH();`, but there's always an error saying:

> The function `steuerungH()` does not exist.

Im not sure what the problem exactly is, because the class in which I wrote the function `void steuerungH();` looks exacltly like the others

```java
float gravity = 0.1;
float speed = 0;

class Steuerung {

  void steuerungH(){
    if (key == UP|| key == 'w') {
      playerYPosition = playerYPosition +speed;
      speed = speed + gravity;
        if (playerYPosition >= 30); {
          speed = speed *-1;
        }
    } else if (key == DOWN ||key == 's') {
      /*Duck methode muss noch geschrieben werden*/
    } else if (key == RIGHT || key == 'd') {
      playerXPosition = playerXPosition +10;
    } else if (key == LEFT ||key == 'a') {
      playerXPosition = playerXPosition -10;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this, Java? Have you tried initializing a constructor of Steuerung class in your main class, and calling the steuerungH() on that constructor?

Comment: @OnurÇevik Please read the tag info <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>!. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought the tag was related to something else. Anyways, I feel like issue is related to calling a function of another class from the main class, without initializing a class object in the main class. Check this: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9111/call-a-method-of-a-class-in-another-class

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks a lot, the error is gone and it seems to work. But even though I can start the program, the funtion `steuerungH();` does not do what I expect it to do (move the object in another class).

Comment: @Rabbid75 it should be global variables I think, they aren't in any class, they are there just like this:
`float playerXPosition;`
`float playerYPosition;`
`float playerWidth;` 
`float playerHeight;`

Comment: It worked, no error and the rectangle is moving. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Rabbid76 That must have been a mistake on my side, I thought I could mark more than one answer as useful. Changed it back, since yours was first. Sorry!

Comment: @Lukas You can accept 1 single question, but you can vote on multiple questions,  by the arrows on the left of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should think about `playerXPosition` and `playerYPosition`. Wouldn't it be better to create a class `Player` with the attributes `playerXPosition` and `playerYPosition` and a method `streuerungH`?

```java
class Player {

    float gravity = 0.1;
    float speed = 0;
    float playerXPosition;
    float playerYPosition;

    // [...]

    void steuerungH(){
        if (key == UP|| key == 'w') {
            playerYPosition = playerYPosition +speed;
            speed = speed + gravity;
            if (playerYPosition >= 30); {
                speed = speed *-1;
            }
        } else if (key == DOWN ||key == 's') {
            /*Duck methode muss noch geschrieben werden*/
        } else if (key == RIGHT || key == 'd') {
            playerXPosition = playerXPosition +10;
        } else if (key == LEFT ||key == 'a') {
            playerXPosition = playerXPosition -10;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Anyway, if you want to keep your current designe, then you have to options to solve the issue:

Create an instance of `Steuerung`. e.g.

```java
Steuerung s = new Steuerung();

void draw() {
    // [...]

    s.streuerungH();

    // [...]
}
```

---

The other option is:

Since [Processing](https://processing.org/) provides functions in global namespace, you can turn `steuerungH` to a function:

```java
float gravity = 0.1;
float speed = 0;

void steuerungH(){
    // [...]
}
```

```java
void draw() {
    // [...]

    streuerungH();

    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new Steuerung object like this

```
Steuerung steuerung = new Steuerung();
```

Then you can call the method with

```
steuerung.steuerungH();
```

When you simply do

```
steuerungH();
```

Java will be looking for a `steuerungH()` method in your Main class which doesn't exist and therefor throws an error.